# Fit name column to filenames length - Keyboard shortcut when "+" is in the same key as "="

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

When using file explorer, some long filenames in the "Names" column of the file explorer get  cut because they are too long. See below which columns I refer to.

[image: Name column in the Windows file explorer]

You can fit the column width to the filenames with the `Ctrl + "+"` [Ctrl and + keys] keyboard shortcut. However, this works when you have a keyboard and a `+` key on its own. In my laptop, the `+` is on top of the `=`, so this keyboard shortcut does not work. Does anyone know how to make it work in this case?

Comment: I have been using this shortcut since Windows95.  I too am interested if there is a way to do it on a laptop. :)  I am glad you asked this question.

Comment: Any keys available for remapping? `~/\`` or `Rt-Ctrl`, or `Rt-Alt` for instance?